# Jumping Spiders in the Holy See

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

> reduce(15:93)
>
> Jumping spiders in the Holy See
>
> From a battle entertainer in the royale court, less than weekly

The answer is two words, and will fit into the sentence, "Video games these days often contain _____ _____."

Hint:

> You will have to do (a small amount of) internet searching to find the answer. Also, royale is not a typo. ;)

Comment: Fairly sure this has something to do with rot13(onggyr eblnyr) but besides that I'm stuck!

Comment: @Grace Indeed. I've edited that line to be slightly more telling what it is referring to, in particular.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer could be:

> "Video games these days often contain **weekly challenges**." And all the clues pertain to *Fortnite: Battle Royale* which includes weekly challenges.

Reduce(15:93)

> This fraction reduces to 5/31, which could read as May 31st - the day in 2018 that Epic Games introduced "Fortnite Week 5 Challenges" to *Fortnite:Battle Royale*.

Jumping spiders in the Holy See

> It has been said that the ingame map is "4x the size of Vatican City" (Vatican City is *The Holy See*). I'm not a Fortnite player myself, but I have seen that Vatican City, Spiders, and Spiderman all feature in gamer streams, not sure if these are mods or not.

From a battle entertainer in the royale court

> A reference to **Battle Royale**

less than weekly

> A "fortnight" is 14 days, which is *more* than a week, and so occurs *less frequently*.

Comment: Regarding the last clue (ROT13): "sbegavtugyl" vf yrff serdhragyl guna "jrrxyl"

Comment: @F1Krazy Ah, see your point now, thank you.

Comment: Creative and plausible answer, but it doesn't quite explain all the choices in words I made (hint: Jul "whzcvat fcvqref"?). I'll also say, that if I meant to indicate 5/31, I would've written reduce(15/93) ;)

Comment: ROT13: 5:31 znl or 5z31f vagb n ivqrb nobhg Sbegavgr:Onggyr Eblnyr. Gur "ragregnvare" znl or n Wrfgre? V ybbxrq gb frr vs gurer ner nal jryy xabja cynlref/fgernzref pnyyrq Wrfgre gung znl unir ivqrbf. Gurer ner n srj Sbegavgr ivqrbf nobhg "ingvpna" (ubyl frr) ohg V qba'g trg gur ersreraprf fb V'yy tvir hc naq yrg fbzrbar ryfr fbyir guvf.